# Shouldn't "remove new user restrictions" be "removed new user restrictions"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges

As it's written now, it sounds as if you can remove some other users' restrictions.

Comment: Where's this text?

Comment: Oh I see. It's one of the privileges on the right side of the [Privileges page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges). @Chris

Comment: @Jon - I thought it was, but didn't want to assume.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't link it, I suddenly had to go so I submitted it as is.

Comment: I'd make it "new user restrictions removed". somehow that sounds less random.